# FFMPEG stop converting from TrueHD to PCM

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion

I'm trying to convert a TrueHD 7.1 soundtrack to PCM format but ffmpeg give me an error and stopped. Here's the output of ffmpeg:

```
user:~$ ffmpeg -i source.thd -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 output.wav      
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    Input #0, truehd, from 'source.thd':
      Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit)
    Output #0, wav, to 'output.wav':
      Metadata:
        ISFT            : Lavf56.40.101
        Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 7.1, s32 (24 bit), 9216 kb/s
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (truehd (native) -> pcm_s24le (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [wav @ 0x206a2e0] Filesize 9129246822 invalid for wav, output file will be broken
    size= 8915280kB time=02:12:04.69 bitrate=9216.0kbits/s    
    video:0kB audio:8915280kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000001%
```

How can I make to conversion successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WAV header is typically 32-bits. Your output will need 64 bits.

```
ffmpeg -i source.thd -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -rf64 auto output.wav
```

Comment: Can you explain more what `-rf64 auto` does? I search the official document but I can't find it explanation.

Comment: If the size of the output file is larger than 2^32-1, the WAV header needs to be 64-bits large. By default, ffmpeg will only write 32-bit headers. With the auto option, ffmpeg will use the variant that works.